# I am using Flask and got an error can you help me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index(1).html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*Below is the error*

I couldn't solve it because it's very complicated and hard for me

I do import all modules that is needed

I do write localhost true

I write html file's name correctly

If you need more information about code,
i will give you.

I reformat file one time

**Thank all of the Stackoverflow communtiy for help:)**

```
C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/90551/PycharmProjects/DövizUygulaması/github.py
 * Serving Flask app "github" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 251-045-188
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\github.py", line 8, in index
    return render_template("index.html")
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:57] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:57] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:57] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:57] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:58] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:58] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\github.py", line 8, in index
    return render_template("index.html")
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\DövizUygulaması\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:59] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:59] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:59] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:59] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2020 16:04:59] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `index(1).html` in your templates folder? If not create a new folder named `templates` and create this file inside that folder.

Comment: @FaizanAmin yes I do have a file named `index(1).html`

Comment: But I'm using PyCharm how will I create a folder without exiting from avaible folder??

Comment: Create folder named `templates` in same directory which contains your python file and place `html` file inside that folder.

Comment: If you have opened a project in pycharm. You can view create file and folder options on `top-left` side

Comment: Do I need to select **Open Project** or only **Open**  I think it is **Open**, right because it has a folder icon on it.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Hmmm, for some reason it seems like Flask is trying to load `index.html` instead of `index(1).html`.

## What to do about it?

Rename your `index(1).html` file to `index.html`, and verify that the `index.html` file is in the `templates` directory, and the `templates` directory is in the same directory as the python script. Then, change your code to reflect this:

```py
# ...
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
# ...
```

Then *fully* rerun your script and everything should work! If that does not work, feel free to reach out! I am here to help!

Comment: ı do create a file named `index.html` and _fully_ rerun the code but it is opening a localhost named `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound` it gives that error in that localhost.

Comment: That means that somehow your folder structure is messed up. Do you think you can edit your question and add how your project is structured (e.g. where the script is, and the `templates` folder)? I would love to try and help once I get a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: İt says wait 5 minute to edit or I was editing it but ı need to wait 5 minutes

Comment: maybe it can be because I do not only got files about Flask I have got lots of other files about other thing maybe it is giving that error for this Do I need to open a new folder that only got `index.html` and  `github.py`(this is my file about github rest api)?